# How to add text on input border?

Tags: html, css, input, border

Do you know how how to create this additional "*Email" text on my input border?

[It should look like this!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UquG.png)

Comment: If that example is from a webpage, can you not examine the markup/styling of that page to see how they did it?  At a glance, unless there's an option I don't know about, I would suspect that it's a separate element styled with a white background and floating partially over the input's border.

Comment: you could use a fieldset and legend to wrap your input then remove the border from your input but then it probably wouldn't be semantically correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.form-group{
  border:1px solid #999;
  margin:10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.form-group>label{
  position:absolute;
  top:-1px;
  left:25px;
  background-color:white;
  color:#666;
  padding:0 5px;
}
.form-group .required{
  color:red;
  padding:0 5px;
}
.form-group>input{
  border:none;
  border:0;
  line-height;100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="form-group">
         <label><span class="required">*</span>Email</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

**Hey**

I'm currently doing a project in React and in there there is something called Material UI and in there there are TextFields. In there they are different types of TextFields like Standard, Filled and Outlined. [Image of TextFields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3HpG.png). The thing is that you can use that for a text box. All of them have text on the top.

```js
return (
        <div className='header'>
            <span className='title'>Word Hunt</span>
            <div className='inputs'>
                <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
                    <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
                </ThemeProvider>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

This is a example from my project. Hope this helps!

https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#text-field